Error Initializing Azure Container App Job: Unsupported 'registry' and 'secret' Block Types in Terraform Configuration
`resource "azurerm_container_app_job" "container_app_job" {
  name                         = "xxx-${var.location_short_name}-${var.environment}"
  location                     = var.location
  resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
  container_app_environment_id = var.ca_environment

  replica_timeout_in_seconds = 10
  replica_retry_limit        = 10

  manual_trigger_config {
    parallelism              = 4
    replica_completion_count = 1
  }

  secrets = [
    {
      name  = "container-registry-password"
      value = var.registry_credentials.registry_key
    }
  ]

  template {
    container {
      name  = "app-container"
      image = "${var.registry_credentials.registry_server_url}/${var.image_name}:${var.environment}"

      env {
        name  = "REGISTRY_USERNAME"
        value = var.registry_credentials.registry_username
      }

      env {
        name  = "REGISTRY_SERVER"
        value = var.registry_credentials.registry_server_url
      }

      env {
        name  = "REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
        secret_ref = "container-registry-password"
      }

      readiness_probe {
        transport = "HTTP"
        port      = 5000
      }

      liveness_probe {
        transport = "HTTP"
        port      = 5000
        path      = "/health"

        header {
          name  = "Cache-Control"
          value = "no-cache"
        }

        initial_delay           = 5
        interval_seconds        = 20
        timeout                 = 2
        failure_count_threshold = 1
      }

      startup_probe {
        transport = "TCP"
        port      = 5000
      }

      cpu    = 0.5
      memory = "1Gi"
    }
  }
}
`

Error:

│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on container-app-jobs/main.tf line 57, in resource "azurerm_container_app_job" "container_app_job":
│   57:   registry ***
│
│ Blocks of type "registry" are not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on container-app-jobs/main.tf line 62, in resource "azurerm_container_app_job" "container_app_job":
│   62:   secret ***
│
│ Blocks of type "secret" are not expected here. Did you mean "secrets"?

Can someone help in this context?

Which version of the azurerm provider are you using? Are you showing the whole relevant code? I don't see any secret nor registry blocks.

I agree @RuiJarimba the error description doesnt match with the configuration you shared LasalSenarath

Can you please share the relevent code that causes error @LasalSenarath

@RuiJarimaba
terraform {
required_providers {
azurerm = {
source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
version = "~>3.104.0"
}
azuread = {
source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
version = "~>2.41.0"
}
azurecaf = {
source  = "aztfmod/azurecaf"
version = "~>1.2.0"
}
}
required_version = "~>1.8.5"
}

If possible try to upgade the version to the latest where it suports secret not secrets and registry follow: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_app_job#secret-2


Unsupported 'registry' and 'secret' Block Types in Terraform Configuration

Thanks Rui Jarimba for pointing in the right direction. Issue seems to be the version used "3.104.0" as per the latest terraform registry the the provider version as of today is "4.13.0".
As per the documentation Where it supports "registry" & "secret" not "secrets" as per error description and comments it seems you're using the key work "secret" inside the configuration
with wrong provider version.
demo configuration using latest version:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "4.13.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
.
.
.
resource "azurerm_container_app_job" "container_app_job" {
  name                         = "testsam-${var.location_short_name}-${var.environment}"
  location                     = var.location
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.ca_env.id

  replica_timeout_in_seconds = 10
  replica_retry_limit        = 10

  manual_trigger_config {
    parallelism              = 4
    replica_completion_count = 1
  }

  template {
    container {
      name  = "app-container"
      image = "${var.registry_credentials.registry_server_url}/${var.image_name}:${var.environment}"

      env {
        name  = "REGISTRY_USERNAME"
        value = var.registry_credentials.registry_username
      }

      env {
        name  = "REGISTRY_SERVER"
        value = var.registry_credentials.registry_server_url
      }

      env {
        name       = "REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
        secret_name = "container-registry-password"
      }

      readiness_probe {
        transport = "HTTP"
        port      = 5000
      }

      liveness_probe {
        transport = "HTTP"
        port      = 5000
        path      = "/health"

        header {
          name  = "Cache-Control"
          value = "no-cache"
        }

        initial_delay           = 5
        interval_seconds        = 20
        timeout                 = 2
        failure_count_threshold = 1
      }

      startup_probe {
        transport = "TCP"
        port      = 5000
      }

      cpu    = 0.5
      memory = "1Gi"
    }
  }

  secret {
    name  = "container-registry-password"
    value = var.registry_credentials.registry_key
  }
}

Deployment:


refer:
azurerm_container_app_job | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
azurerm_container_app_job | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry answered by Venkat V
